# How to exclude specific parts of an Ivy dependency on Android

Tags: android, scala, ivy, apache-kafka

I'm working on an Android app that will use [Kafka](http://kafka.apache.org/). It has a ton of dependencies, so I've decided to use Ivy to manage them (though I've never used it before, and I'm inexperienced with Apache stuff in general).

My problem is that one of Kafka's dependencies, [snappy-java](https://code.google.com/p/snappy-java/), has a "native" folder with native libraries for linux, mac and windows, and Android is throwing the error `The library 'snappy-java-1.0.4.1.jar' contains native libraries that will not run on the device.` If I were just including the libraries manually, I would take out the snappy-java jar, recompile it from source without the `native` folder, and put it back in the project. Since Ivy is building it automatically, I think I have to do it through the `ivy.xml` file, but I'm not sure how.

I'm trying to exclude the folder from the dependency directly:

```
    <dependency org="org.xerial.snappy" name="snappy-java" rev="1.0.4.1" conf="compile->default(compile)">
        <exclude org="org.xerial.snappy" module="snappy-java/native" name="*" type="*" ext="*" matcher="exact"/>
    </dependency>
```

But this doesn't change anything. I've looked at the Ivy documentation on the `<exclude>`, and it seems like it's more for excluding transitive dependencies, or for excluding whole modules. Is it possible to get more specific?

It seems like there might be a way to do it by messing with `<conf>` and `<artifact>` in snappy-java's ivy file, but I haven't been able to get that to work either, and I think Ivy generates those files automatically anyway. Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you use sbt (which has ivy underneath)?

Comment: Ivy is a manager of file based dependencies. You're trying to excludes stuff that is inside those files, ivy does not support this. Simplest solution is to recompile snappy (as you've described) and store the result in a local repository.